# Oracle - SQL Loader cannot load Registered symbol

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I had tried numerous settings to load a data file using SQL Loader to the database, but the special characters are not loaded in correctly.

My database is using `AL32UTF8` as the character set.

I tried manually run an `insert` statement to update the table with the special characters and the data is correct.

With the CTL below, i try to load it and the character become a square:

```
load data
CHARACTERSET 'UTF8'
infile 'data.csv' "str '|\n'"
BADFILE 'data.bad'
DISCARDFILE 'data.dsc'
TRUNCATE
into table data_list
fields terminated by '^' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
data_part,
MFG_NOTES CHAR(800),
MFG_NOTES_TYPE CHAR(800)
)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: 200+ results searching for `[oracle] AL32UTF8`, with 16 results for `[oracle] AL32UTF8 import`. Good luck.

Comment: What character set is your data file encoded using?  I would guess it is not UTF-8

Comment: Thanks @JustinCave , the encoding of the file is the issue. I'll close this question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a range of character set encoding that you can use in control file while loading data from sql loader.

```
LOAD DATA
CHARACTERSET WE8ISO8859P1
```

or in case of MS word input files with smart characters try in control file

```
LOAD DATA
CHARACTERSET WE8MSWIN1252
```